# How to inject non static, on demand NativeModules into React Native Android?

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native, kotlin

In a hybrid app where multiple `Activity`/`Fragment` instances nesting their own `ReactRootView`s share a single `ReactInstanceManager` instance, there seems to be no official way to inject a native module per `Activity`/`Fragment` instance. By nature, native modules are singleton like javascript modules residing in a `.js` file. This is not the intended behavior if JS code running inside different instances of the same `Fragment` wants to access Java/Kotlin side to interact with the local properties of the `Fragment`.

I tried using `registerAdditionalPackages()` method of `ReactInstanceManager` but it fails with an assertion error like below if used simultaneously by multiple `Fragment`s/`Activity`s.

`"Extending native modules with non-matching application contexts."`

It wasn't a thread safety issue but a design consequence of `registerAdditionalPackages()` implementation. Is there another way, and if so, how do you access the injected module on the JS side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem kept me awake for days. Finally, I have a solution. I hope it helps someone in the future. The solution is in Kotlin but it is quite straightforward to translate it into Java. `someVariable!!` is a "not null" assertion, uppercase `SomeObject()` calls are instance creation, `SomeType:SomeOtherType` is inheritence or implementation, `val someVar:SomeType` is a variable declaration. The rest is the same.

Steps:

**1)** Run the below code at the time you want to inject a module to your RN runtime. Inside of `Activity.onCreate()` or `Fragment.onCreateView()` are some good candidates. `mReactInstanceManager` is your singleton, global react runtime. `packageToInject` definition will be given later.

```
synchronized(mReactInstanceManager!!.currentReactContext!!) {
    val nativeModuleRegistryBuilder = NativeModuleRegistryBuilder(
        mReactInstanceManager!!.currentReactContext as ReactApplicationContext?, 
        mReactInstanceManager!!, 
        false
    )

    nativeModuleRegistryBuilder.processPackage(packageToInject)
    mReactInstanceManager!!.currentReactContext!!.catalystInstance!!.extendNativeModules(nativeModuleRegistryBuilder.build())
}
```

**2)** Instance held inside `packageToInject` must be prepared like below to have a unique module with a unique name per `Fragment`/`Activity` instance. Make these inner classes of your `Fragment` or `Activity`.

```
class ReactManagerPackage : ReactPackage {
    override fun createViewManagers(reactContext: ReactApplicationContext): List<ViewManager<*, *>> {
        return emptyList()
    }

    override fun createNativeModules(reactContext: ReactApplicationContext): List<NativeModule> {
        val modules = ArrayList<NativeModule>()
        modules.add(ReactBridge(reactContext))
        return modules
    }
}

class ReactBridge(reactContext: ReactApplicationContext) : ReactContextBaseJavaModule(reactContext) {
    override fun getName(): String {
        return myFragmentOrActivity.hashCode().toString()
    }

    @ReactMethod
    fun showToast(text: String) {
        Toast.makeText(text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }  
}
```

**3)** Pass the `myFragmentOrActivity.hashCode().toString()` as a prop when you initiate `mReactRootView.startReactApplication()` either in your `Activity.onCreate()` or `Fragment.onCreateView()` . Put it in the bundle that you give to `mReactRootView.startReactApplication()` as 3rd argument.

```
val bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putString("fragmentOrActivityHash", myFragmentOrActivity.hashCode().toString())
mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "MyRootComponent", bundle )
```

**4)** Use the prop in your component (`MyRootComponent` in this example) to retrieve your specific bridge. (Javascript)

```
NativeModules[this.props.fragmentOrActivityHash].showToast("It works")
```

Profit!